# Font replacement for DR Agu Sans Black

Tags: fonts, font-identification, font-recommendation

There's that beautiful DR Agu Sans Black:

https://www.myfonts.com/fonts/rastvortsev/dr-agu-sans/black/

[image]

Do you know any free/cheaper replacements for that?
I've tried [ObelixPro](https://www.dafont.com/obelixpro.font) and [LuckiestGuy](https://www.1001fonts.com/luckiest-guy-font.html), but they seem too "sharp".

Answer (score 1):

Some free options:

[Funkhouse](https://www.searchfreefonts.com/free/funkhouse.htm) via searchfreefonts.com

[image: Funkhouse]

[Dom Bold](https://www.dafontfree.net/freefonts-dombold-bt-f121808.htm) via dafontfree.net

[image: Dom BOld]

[Foo](https://www.dafont.com/foo.font?text=NOSTRUD%20EXERCITAT) via dafont.com

[image: FOO]